# MS SQL 2008 cast null to string

Tags: sql-server, string, casting, null

I got a few stored procedures that uses a TRY/CATCH statement, so i execute the main program and if it generates any errors i catch them. Now my problem is in the catch statement, i have this piece of code:

```
            BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO ContentTypes (ContentName, ContentPath) VALUES (@ContentName, @ContentPath)

        SET @QResult = 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH         

        SET @QResult = 1
        INSERT INTO Errors (ErrorNumber, ErrorLine, ErrorProcedure, ErrorSeverity, ErrorState, ErrorParameters)
        VALUES (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(), 'ContentName:' + @ContentName + ',ContentPath:' + @ContentPath)
        RETURN
    END CATCH
```

This works perfectly until ContentName is NULL then it crashes, i forgot that you need to cast the values to string before you can add them to a nvarchar column. So how do i convert 
@ContentName before i insert it into the Errors table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to cast - use the [`coalesce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28SQL.80%29.aspx) function:

> Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

You would use it like this:

```
insert into Errors (ErrorNumber, ErrorLine, 
    ErrorProcedure, ErrorSeverity, ErrorState, ErrorParameters)
values (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
    ERROR_STATE(), 'ContentName:' 
    + coalesce(@ContentName, '')
    + ',ContentPath:' + coalesce(@ContentPath, ''))
```

As a side note, SQL server offers [`cast` and `convert` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx) that you can use to convert data from one type to another.  You don't need it here but it is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

as an extra point to [@Andrew Hare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450821/ms-sql-2008-cast-null-to-string/1450830#1450830), I would format your strings a little differently:

```
insert into Errors (ErrorNumber, ErrorLine, 
    ErrorProcedure, ErrorSeverity, ErrorState, ErrorParameters)
values (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
    ERROR_STATE()
    ,'ContentName:' + coalesce('"'+@ContentName+'"', 'null') 
    + ',ContentPath:' + coalesce('"'+@ContentPath+'"', 'null')
```

doing it this way, you can tell if the variable was an empty string or was null.  The variables will have their value between double quotes, so *""* is an empty string, and *" "* is a single space and *null* would be null.  Bugs crop up quite often with these three values.